# Define a Class Function Operator

Tags: php

How can I define in PHP a class `Foo` that allows to do something like:

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar;
$foo();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/504/classes-and-objects#t=201609051452012077782

Comment: Start by reading the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) but what do you expect `$foo->bar` and `$foo()` to actually do?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code, assuming `Foo` has an `__invoke` method.

Comment: Just because you don't know about all features of PHP doesn't mean this code is invalid. I suggest y'all read http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke and learn something today.

Comment: @MadDog, fair, but the OP would still have done themselves a service by explaining what they expect that code to _do_. The question was not clearly asked no matter how you slice it. I'm _still_ not sure what `$foo->bar;` is meant to do, or how it fits into the question.

Comment: Well said @Chris as it stands the question is poor/misleading at best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking about invokable objects, or treating objects as functions. To be able to do that, you need to implement `__invoke()` method, like this:

```
class Foo {
    public function __invoke()
    {
        echo 'invoke!';
    }
}
```

Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke

Also, you can call `$foo->bar;` as many times as you want, just as you can write: `$a = 5; $a;` - but it will have no effect. It's just a field. If it's a callable, you'll have to add parentheses to call it.